# Internal QTimer isn't killed from the right thread when terminating a QThread

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qtimer

I have a QThread that creates a QGraphicsSimpleTextItem.
When I close my application I try to finish the thread and then terminate it.

```
if( !QThread::wait(1000) )
    QThread::terminate();
```

Everything is fine until I add a call to `QGraphicsSimpleTextItem::setFont()` in my thread. If I do so, Qt's internal QFontCache system is called and will start a QTimer (from my thread).
Then when I terminate the QThread, killTimer is called (from the main) when Qt cleans up the event loops and I get the error:

```
QObject::killTimers: timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

What should I do to avoid this problem? Shouldn't that be considered as a bug of the font caching mechanism?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: why does the QFontCache start a timer? can you explain in more detail what happens?

Comment: Looks like it is for cache maintenance, I guess they don't want to keep a big cache if it's not required. It happens in qfont.cpp: void QFontCache::increaseCost(uint cost)

Comment: I guess the problem is that you do GUI stuff in a non-GUI thread, see for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545961/modify-qt-gui-from-background-worker-thread. You should move the call to `setFont()` to the GUI thread.